# Tor fuctionality on XP home service pack 2

Tags: configuration, windows, vpn

XP is light and IMO just as fast browsing the internet then any later OS. Is there anything about Tor browser that doesn't work on XP home then a newer OS? What patches will I need if any?

Comment: Why are you still using Windows XP? Support for Windows XP (an 18 years old operating system) ended 4 years ago ...

Comment: See https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-dev/2019-February/013694.html and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about trying the operating system called "Tails" on a live usb drive? It works with older hardware too. You can save XP on the computer. Nothing happens and anything you do will not be saved on the computer.